# Changing the referencing format for apacite

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{billioandrew,
    author  = "Billio, M. and Getmansky, M. and Lo, A. and Pelizzon, L.",
    title   = "Econometric measures of connectedness and systemic risk in the finance and insurance sectors",
    year    = "2012",
    journal = "Journal of Financial Economics",
    volume  = "104",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "535--559"}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliography}      
\end{document}
```

The output in the reference list is as follows:

[image]

However, I want the output to be:

Billio, M., Getmansky, M., Lo, A., Pelizzon, L., 2012. Econometric measures of connectedness and systemic risk in the finance and insurance sectors. Journal of Financial Economics 104(3), 535-559

---

Note the following changes:

1) A comma after the last author (eg, L., instead of L.)

2) No brackets around the year (eg, 2012 instead of (2012))

3) No italics for the journal name (eg, Journal of Financial Economics instead of *Journal of Financial Economics*)

4) No italics for volume number (eg, 104 instead of *104*)

5) No comma after the journal name and before the volume number (eg, Journal of Financial Economics 104(3) instead of Journal of Financial Economics, 104(3))

6) No `&` symbol before the final author/editor in a multi-author/editor list

---

I'd also like to have the same set of rules apply for `@misc` as well.

However, I want the in-text citation to remain the same, I only want the above to apply to the reference list output.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's easy to do with `biblatex` as it uses a latex-like syntax. Note there exists a `bilatex-apa` style.

Comment: @Bernard, Could you run me through the steps? I am a complete novice when it comes to bibliographies in latex as I've only just started to use it and barely know the syntax/processes.

Comment: I'll look at your code. Perhaps what you ask has already been done.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding an additional item to the list of changes you would like to get.

Comment: I think that you have sufficiently many change requests -- keeping in mind that the formatting changes will need to be applied to more than a dozen different entry types -- that you may be best off creating an *entirely new bibliography style* using the menu-based, questions-and-multiple-choice-question-and-answers `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/). Give it a try -- I think you'll be surprised how smooth the process is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. Note that `biblatex` allows to emulate `natbib` commands. In particular, in this mode you can always write `\citep` but actually it is translated into biblatex's command `\parencite`.
More importantly, the syntax is slighly different: `\bibliography{name_of_the_bibfile} in the body of the document is replaced with:

1. `\addbibresource{name_of_the_bibfile.bib}` in the preamble
2. `\printbibliography` in the body of the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{billioandrew,
    author  = {Billio, M. and Getmansky, M. and Lo, A. and Pelizzon, L.},
    title   = {Econometric measures of connectedness and systemic risk in the finance and insurance sectors},
    year    = {2012},
    journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume  = {104},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {535--559}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%original
\ifnameundef{author}
{\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
{\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
 \setunit*{\addspace}%
 \printfield{nameaddon}%
 \ifnameundef{with}
   {}
   {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
    \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
    \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuename}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{yearorunkyear}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{doubtfuldate}{true}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{ca\adddot\addspace#1}}
    {#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

\AtBeginBibliography{
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
  {}
  {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
     {\finalandcomma\addspace}
     {\addspace\&\space}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
{\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ \finalandcomma\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\usebibmacro{cite}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}%
\usebibmacro{cite:post}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

As we see in \parencite{billioandrew},…

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Requested changes 1 and 6 are missing. :-)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for that! In addition to changes 1 and 6, I copy and pasted your code exactly as above into a new document, however I do not get a references list and my output in text appears as: As we see in **(billioandrew )**,. . .

Comment: @Mico: it's not really hard, but rather long — the time to check odds and ends… For the comma it's done, I'll check the rest.

Comment: @TrueTears: Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX? For the citation, do you mean you have only one author? and in boldface?

Comment: @Bernard I use TexnicCenter and normally for bibliographies I just press ALT+F7 three times (LaTeX => PDF), how do I run Biber? I think that's the step I'm missing. Regarding the output, it is exactly as shown with the label bolded, I think it's because I'm not outputting it properly haha...

Comment: I don't know well TeXnic Center. I think you have to go to the `Build` menu and select the `define Output Profiles…` submenu. You then should define a profile named, say, `PDFLaTeX+BIBER`. The simplest way to do that is to copy thePDFLaTeX profile and change the executable for bibtex, replacing it with the path to biber.  I hope there is no problem with parameters (I'm not sure they're exactly the same as for bibtex). Then you should compiling after you've selected that profile exactly the same way as before. If it doen't work, you should post a question.

Comment: @TrueTears: I've modified the code. Hope I didn't forget anything :).